# Display and create mongoose schema via angularjs form?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, http, post, mongoose

Using the code below, I am able to create a rule via terminal using:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: applcation/json' -d '{"name": "ITS ABOUT TIME!", "desc":"another is a db test working well!", "color":"02"}' http://localhost:5000/rules
```

and display via {{ruler.name}} and {{ruler.desc}}

...yet I cant figure out how to apply this to the form.  I am blurry eyed looking at this, so any direction and help would be greatly appreciated.

The question in all of this is: how do I create a rule via the angular form.

form front-end:

```
<form action="/rules" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name of the new Rule"ng-model="ruler.name"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="small description of this rule" ng-model="ruler.desc"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btnCreate" ng-click="creatRule()">CREATE</button>
</form>
```

model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var RuleSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    desc: {type: String},
    color: {type: String}
});

var RuleModel = mongoose.model('Rule', RuleSchema);
exports.index = function (req, res){
    return RuleModel.find(function (err, rules) {
        if (!err) {
            res.jsonp(rules);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}

exports.findById = function (req, res) {
    return RuleModel.findById(req.params.id, function (err, rule) {
        if (!err) {
            res.jsonp(rule);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}

exports.addRule = function (req, res) {
    var rule;
    rule = new RuleModel({
        name: req.body.name,
        desc: req.body.desc,
        color: req.body.color
    });
    rule.save(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("created");
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

    return res.send(rule);
}

exports.updateRule = function (req, res) {
    return RuleModel.findById(req.params.id, function (err, rule) {
        rule.name = req.body.name;
        rule.phone = req.body.desc;
        rule.color = req.body.color;
        rule.save(function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log("updated");
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
            res.send(rule);
        });
    });
}

exports.deleteRule = function (req, res) {
    return RuleModel.findById(req.params.id, function (err, rule) {
        return rule.remove(function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log("removed");
                return res.send('');
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

angularjs:

```
$scope.createRule = function () {
        $http({method: 'jsonp', url: '/rules?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'})
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.rulers = data;
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('error in rule creation');
            });
    }
```

server:

```
var express  = require('express');
var rules    = require("./model/ruleModel");
var app      = express();

app.get("/", rules.index);
app.get('/rules', rules.index);
app.get('/rules/:id', rules.findById);
app.post('/rules', rules.addRule);
app.put('/rules/:id', rules.updateRule);
app.delete('/rules/:id', rules.deleteRule);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because you are using JSONP which trigger a GET request to your node server. According to your configuration, you want to use a standard POST request :

```
$scope.createRule = function () {
    $http.post('/rules', $scope.ruler)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.rulers = data;
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('error in rule creation');
        });
}
```

[$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) is asynchronous, you don't want to specify any action or method attribute in the form element :

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name of the new Rule" ng-model="ruler.name"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="small description of this rule" ng-model="ruler.desc"/>
    <button class="btnCreate" ng-click="createRule()">CREATE</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes I have refactored this a little but also saw your post as useful info so I vote it as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else who might be interested I ended up using:

```
 $scope.createRule = function () {
        Rules.create($scope.formData)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.formData = {};
                $scope.rules = data;
            });
    };
```

and then created a factory to tie into the routes:

```
.factory('Rules', function($http) {
    return {
        get : function() {
            return $http.get('/api/rules');
        },
        create : function(ruleData) {
            return $http.post('/api/rules', ruleData);
        },
        delete : function(id) {
            return $http.delete('/api/rules/' + id);
        }
    }
});
```